# Two interpretations of a sentence that changes the agency

Tags: german-to-english

The following is a footnote from a [Journal Article written in 1955](https://www.jstor.org/stable/25753343) by [Hubert Walter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubert_Walter_(anthropologist)):

> <sup>1</sup> Interessant ist in diesem Zusammenhang ein Zitat aus H. TRIMBORN „Indianische
> Welt", Iserlohn 1947: „Die Inkas achteten bei der zwangsweisen Umsiedlung von Völkerschaften darauf, daß es sich um Bewohner aus einem ähnlichen Klima handelte." (S. 80.)

The machine translation of the quote is either interpreted as the Incas being "forced to resettle peoples", removing agency from their actions, while the other reads it as "forcibly relocating peoples":

[Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/?sl=de&tl=en&text=Die%20Inkas%20achteten%20bei%20der%20zwangsweisen%20Umsiedlung%20von%20V%C3%B6lkerschaften%20darauf%2C%20da%C3%9F%20es%20sich%20um%20Bewohner%20aus%20einem%20%C3%A4hnlichen%20Klima%20handelte&op=translate)

> When forced to resettle peoples, the Incas made sure that they came from a similar climate

[DeepL Translate](https://www.deepl.com/en/translator#de/en/Die%20Inkas%20achteten%20bei%20der%20zwangsweisen%20Umsiedlung%20von%20V%C3%B6lkerschaften%20darauf%2C%20da%C3%9F%20es%20sich%20um%20Bewohner%20aus%20einem%20%C3%A4hnlichen%20Klima%20handelte)

> The Incas, when forcibly relocating peoples, made sure that they were inhabitants from a similar climate

While the DeepL translation is in line with our current understanding of Inca policies I wanted some human input to confirm the DeepL translation is a more accurate reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taken literally, the original just means "during the forced resettlement of peoples". That could in theory mean either of these things.

Of course the translation you got from DeepL is what is actually meant by this. This is just an example of computers not understanding the real world very well.

Comment: The translated time span contributes much less to meaning of the sentence than the subject, which leaves the first paragraph nit exactly helpful.

Comment: It might be worth noting that "forced" in the sense of "being enforced by external circumstances" would rather be expressed by "bei der erzwungenen ..." and not "bei der zwangsweisen ..."

Comment: The word zwangsweise here means that the Völkerschaften are being forced not the Incas. The dual meaning of who is forced only arises in the English translation.